# How to use refresh (F5) to update api background image?

Tags: html, css

I have an api (https://api.daihan.top/api/acg) for Random images. I use it for a website background image in css file.I want use F5 to fresh website to have a new background image.

But, in my code, use refresh it doesn't work.Use refresh it is still the old picture.Unless I close the entire webpage and reopen it, it can get a new background image.

And this is my css code:

```
.mask {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-image: url('https://api.daihan.top/api/acg');
}
```

I want to use refresh to have new background image, what should I do.

---

NEW UPDATE:
I found that when in my computer Local environment, I can use refresh o update image. But when I deploy it in github pages, refresh doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably caching the API. You could add a request parameter that adds a random number on every refresh, if you apply the style directly on the div, assuming you are using JavaScript. That way GitHub would think you are loading a different API every time and not cache.

Below is an example of how to do that in ReactJS.

```
style={{backgroundImage: `url('https://api.daihan.top/api/acg'?${Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)})`}}
```

Comment: No you can't run it in the snippet but the backticks required for this snippet were getting negated by stack overflow editor, so I had to use the snippet editor.  But it will work as stated in your code.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. thank you!^_^

Comment: :) good luck!  If you share your markup and js it would help diagnose the issue more precisely.

Comment: thank you, the random number Solve my problem.   : )  And I have share my solution code under here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Authentic-Science solution, I add a random number on css link in html head file and did solve the problem.
This is my new code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="link" href="./source/main.css">
<script  type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("link").href="./source/main.css?random=" + Math.random();
</script>
```

In Github pages, when I refresh, it can change the background image.

P.S. I didn't change my css file.